# Disable "Response receipt" in a google form using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using Google Apps Script to generate a form, however when I `setCollectEmail(true)` the Response receipt option is toggled automatically. I would like to disable it, but I can't seem to find a way by looking at the documentation.

How can I achieve that ?